# Are the Warhammer stories about Mousilion based on real legends?

Tags: warhammer-fantasy

The Old World is heavily based on real Europe - Bretonnia is medieval France, Empire is late Renaissance Germany, Kislev is Russia etc. Our legends also have their place there - in example the infamous vampire-plagued Sylvania with its Drakenhof castle is of course based on story about count Dracula ("Dracula" means "son of a dragon" in Romanian, "Drakenhof" is "Dragon's court" in German).

And there is [Mousillion](http://warhammeronline.wikia.com/wiki/Mousillon) - the, dukedom of Bretonnia, where cursed, mutants and undead freely walk the streets:

- [Duke Merovech](http://warhammeronline.wikia.com/wiki/Merovech) led successful campaign against the ratmen and saved Bretonnia, although many of his companions were terrified by his bloodthirsty manners - he kept hacking the dead bodies and kept walking covered in blood. On the victory banquet, the guests were accompanied by impaled criminals. Later on, Merovech insulted the king and then killed him and drank his blood.
- Duke Jean-Luc invited nobles from all castles during the red pox plague - while peasants were dying in thousands, nobles were celebrating in never ending balls and banquets. On [Geheimnisnacht](http://whfb.lexicanum.com/wiki/Geheimnisnacht) (night of myseries, the most ominous day in the year) a strange visitor garbed in black and red and carrying a scythe is said to have infiltrated, bringing the Pox to its participants. The next day, the Pox had left the city, the nobles were found dead, marked by the disease.
- Last but not least, Duke Maldred kidnapped the Fey Enchantress (equivalent of kidnapping the Pope) and declared that he found and kept the [Holy Grail](http://warhammerfantasy.wikia.com/wiki/Holy_Grail) (Grail CAN be found  - the Lady has it, but no mortal can keep it).
- Currently the city is under rule by mysterious Black Knights that never rise their visors.

EDIT: I've just found that the Jean-Luc story is based on the Edgar Allan Poe "[The Masque of the Red Death](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Masque_of_the_Red_Death)":

> The story follows Prince Prospero's attempts to avoid a dangerous plague, known as the Red Death, by hiding in his abbey. He, along with many other wealthy nobles, hosts a masquerade ball within seven rooms of the abbey, each decorated with a different color. In the midst of their revelry, a mysterious figure disguised as a Red Death victim enters and makes his way through each of the rooms. Prospero dies after confronting this stranger, whose "costume" proves to contain nothing tangible inside it; the guests also die in turn.

Comment: Don't forget  the lady of the sea, and the green knight which are as far as I know also legends in real life.

Comment: Yes, but they are more related to Bretonnia in general, not Mousillion

Comment: yepp that is true. Although wasn't the city also plagued by a undead plague within the city walls? (in the crypts) I think I remember something there from the vampire army book.